# Compare dates in MySQL using CASE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am stuck on trying to use some sql to figure out if a date is within 90, 60, or 30 days.  I think I am close but can't get it to work properly.  I have a column named boosterDate and it's a date in MySQL.  That column I want to check to see if it is within 90, 60, or 30 days from DATE(Now()) and then set the column boosterWithinDays to either 90, 60, or 30 days.  The table name is service.

Here is where I am so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT
     CASE WHEN DATE(boosterDate) < ADDDATE(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL 90 DAY) THEN 90
     WHEN DATE(boosterDate) < ADDDATE(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL 60 DAY) THEN 60
     WHEN DATE(boosterDate) < ADDDATE(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN 30
     ELSE NULL END FROM service;";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN DATE(boosterDate) < ADDDATE(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 90 DAY) THEN 90
             WHEN DATE(boosterDate) < ADDDATE(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 60 DAY) THEN 60
             WHEN DATE(boosterDate) < ADDDATE(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN 30
             ELSE NULL
       END)
FROM service
```

My guess is that your problem is that this is always returning 90.  The simple reason is that when the second and third conditions are true, then so is the first.  The `case` statement stops at the first matching statement.

So, reverse the conditions:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN DATE(boosterDate) < ADDDATE(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN 30
             WHEN DATE(boosterDate) < ADDDATE(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 60 DAY) THEN 60
             WHEN DATE(boosterDate) < ADDDATE(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 90 DAY) THEN 90
             ELSE NULL
       END)
FROM service
```

Comment: How do I get then the column boosterWithinDays to either be 90, 60, or 30 days though.  So I need to loop through boosterDate, find if the date is within 30, 60 , or 90 days and then set another column to either 30, 60, or 90.

Comment: @ndjustin20 . . . That is what the second query does.

Comment: I see it's the AS boosterWithinDAys part I was missing completely.  And yes I had the logic a little backwards I see now lol  Thank you for the solution.  Do you know any good sites to learn more sql and not just the basics?  I'm finding the manual a bit difficult to follow at this point.

Comment: @ndjustin20: I would personally go to a library and check for a books about "SQL".

Comment: I can see in sqlfiddle that it works to output but for some reason it simply will not update the booserWithinDays column.  I have the boosterDate column in the format as Date and not DateTime.  I tried changing the format and it still doesn't work.  The boosterWithinDays column just won't update with this code as I've copied it and pasted it in the query.  I can get the same output in phpmyadmin but I still can't get the column boosterWithinDays to update.  Am I missing an UPDATE or SET option somewhere maybe?